# UTF-8 encoding issue in php, special characters

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to recreate a string but I am having issues with the utf-8 encoding (I guess?)

I am using the code below to format a string

```
$pre_subject = (strip_tags(html_entity_decode($temp_subject)));
$pre_subject = str_replace('Â', '', $pre_subject);
$pre_subject = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $pre_subject);
```

The problem is that instead of getting the result as in the 1st sentence below, I get a result as the second one.

```
1st. summary: SHANGHAI room - Réunion 
2nd. summary: SHANGHAI room - R'eunion
```

I need to keep the format as the first example, how can I modify my code for that?

Comment: Can you add the original value?

Comment: @Hackerman well, I only pasted a piece of the example, but It would be something like :   SHANGHAI room - RÃ©union SSC/ROC<font size="2"><span style="font-size:10pt;"><div class="PlainText">&nbsp;</div></span></font>2017-06-01 11:002017-06-01 12:0000

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just because `ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` is doing just that, what you got...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I want to remove html tags, the thing is that even after strip_tags I am left with some special characters

Comment: The `iconv()` call replaces all non-ASCII characters with characters that look alike he original ones... Hence the `é`->`'e` transliteration...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto ugh I didn't know. So how can I fix it? If I remove iconv then I am stuck with characters like Â, Â@ etc

Comment: Those are `UTF-8` characters: if you use them in `UTF-8` capable "places", (like a HTML page that uses `UTF-8`,) they will be good.

Comment: Try `utf8_decode()`ing them, or using a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag.

Comment: @ishegg sorry but how do I implement that in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string has UTF-8 characters. You need to either decode them, or tell whatever is reading it to use UTF-8 encoding.

So, this:

```
$pre_subject = (strip_tags(html_entity_decode($temp_subject)));
$pre_subject = str_replace('Â', '', $pre_subject); // if this was trying to fix the problem, remove it
$pre_subject = utf8_decode($pre_subject);
```

Or add this to `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Great, one more thing please, I get an empty space at the end, and I tried to use trim but it won't work, can you help me with that?

Comment: Could you fix it? Well, the excerpt you posted in your question's comments show you have some HTML outputting that space: `<font size="2"><span style="font-size:10pt;"><div class="PlainText">&nbsp;</div></span></font>`, you need to get rid of that.

Comment: in this case it's fine, but I am applying it to some other strings, and I get the question mark. I saw this fix: mb_substr($entry->description, 0, 490, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 1):

Make you PHP header like:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

also, when dealing with utf-8, if you need to do string replace use mb_str_replace and not str_replace