# question mark in diamond shaped box php encoding

Tags: php

I have this string $temp_string which equals to:

```
$temp_string = '<font size="2"><span style="font-size:10pt;"><div class="PlainText">&nbsp;</div></span></font>'
```

What I want to do is to remove the html tags and for that I do:

```
$pre_body = (strip_tags(html_entity_decode($temp_body))); 
$pre_body =utf8_decode($pre_body);
$a['body'] = $pre_body;
```

It gets rid of the html tags but it returns a question mark in a diamond box. I tried to set the header at utf-8 but it didn't work...

Comment: didn't you already post something for this same issue earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45947976/1415724 - if that answer you accepted didn't solve it, then why accept it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes indeed, but actually I didn't notice this issue back then. Only when i debug i get the question mark.

Comment: it's definitely an encoding issue somewhere

Comment: try setting an encoding in the third argument of `html_entity_decode()`   http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: it only happens when there is a &nbsp;

Comment: Just curious as to where `$temp_body` is coming from, I guess you meant `$temp_string`? and what is its origin for the `&nbsp;` to begin with?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it comes from outlook365 calendar

Comment: there may be relevance here